# How to get a reference to the Quartz Scheduler in ServletContextListener? (struts 2)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

```
 public class TomcatStopListener implements ServletContextListener {


  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

   // How to get reference of already running Quartz Scheduler  here??


      }  

}
```

On the stop of tomcat server, I want to stop the quartz scheduler to avoid errors, I know scheduler.shutdown(); but how can i get the reference to the scheduler here?

Comment: The simplest way is to put the scheduler instance in servlet context. How are you starting it? And when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used `QuartzInitializerServlet` to initialise your Quartz, then you can do something like

```
 StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx
            .getAttribute(QuartzFactoryServlet.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
```

inside your `contextDestroyed` method, where `ctx` is your ServletContext.
StdSchedulerFactory instance is stored into the ServletContext.

For more information refer to [Quartz Initializer Servlet](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html)

Comment: Thanks..
Still I had to add below  declaration and setAttribute of QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY in my QuartzSchedulerListener class to make it working:-

public static final String QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY = "org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY";

ServletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY, factory);